# C# DataTable ItemArray returns '{}' - how can I test for null value?

Tags: c#, datatable, null, datarow

I have a `DataTable resultSet;` - I'm trying to check fields for null, but get an '{}' (empty-set ?) object back. Searches involving "{}" aren't yielding any appropriate solutions.

This is the code that isn't working as expected when the "fk_id" field is null:

```
if (resultSet.Rows[0].ItemArray[resultSet.Columns.IndexOf("fk_id")] == null)
{
   //never reaches here
}
```

Note: using an int index instead of the `Columns.IndexOf()` isn't the issue.

Also does the "{}" have some other name in C#?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To check a column for DBNull in a DataSet, you can use the [IsNull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.isnull.aspx) method:

```
if (resultSet.Rows[0].IsNull("fk_id"))
```

Your comparison against `null` is probably failing because DataSets don't use `null` to represent a "database NULL" value - they use [DBNull.Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value.aspx). If you need your code to work the way you've presented it, try this:

```
if (resultSet.Rows[0].ItemArray[resultSet.Columns.IndexOf("fk_id")] == DBNull.Value)
```

Comment: Great thank you, completely forgot about "DBNull.Value" - it's been a while since I've manipulated data sets

Comment: I wonder why they designed it this way instead of just using null?

Comment: @k.rob Because there was no Nullable<T> in .NET 1.0, so there was no way to represent an Int32 value of "null".

Comment: you can also use Convert.IsDBNull(value)

Answer (score -2):

```
try
{
    if (DT.Rows[0][0] != null)
    {      
      //your code
    }    
}    
catch    
{    
    MessageBox.Show("AUTHANICATION FAILED.");    
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Please use:

```
dataTable.Select("FieldName is NULL")
```

this will give you the DataRows with null values in FieldName column.